# elements of topology is open set?

Tags: general-topology

Let's consider the topological space $(\mathbb{R},2^\mathbb{R})$, then each interval is element of topology $2^\mathbb{R}$, but as usually, we consider $[a,b]$ as as closed set.

So my question is

1. Is $[a,b]$ an open set in topology $2^\mathbb{R}$
2. Does the definition of **open set** come after the specific topology?

Comment: a set is open iff its complement is closed

Comment: Yes, any subset of $\mathbb R$ is an open set in the topology $2^{\mathbb R}$. Also, any subset is closed in $\mathbb R$ in the topology $2^{\mathbb R}$. The topology defines the notion of open set.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews so $[a,b]$ is closed set too, in this case?

Comment: Yes, every subset of $\mathbb R$ is closed and open in this topology. This is sometimes called the "discrete topology."

Comment: @Thomas Andrews is $2^{\mathbb{R}} $ the power set of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: It is an unfortunately choice of words in topology, since in non-math english, things can't be both "open" and "closed," but in topology, it is possible for sets to be both open and closed.

Comment: It's a common shorthand for the power-set of $\mathbb R$. I dislike that shothand, but it is the only reading that makes sense here. @vidyarthi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every set including closed intervals is open in that topology: that's what $2^{\mathbb R}$ means: It contains every set.

Every set is also closed in that topology, since a closed set in a topological space is simply any set whose complement is open.

The topology is simply the collection of all open sets in the space.

Comment: Does it mean it is nonsense to talk about **open set** without giving a specific topology?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to call a set open unless you've at least tacitly defined some topology.  But you might say, for example, that an open set is any set in a specified metric space that is a union of open balls, and define an open ball as the set of all points less than a specified distance from a specified point.  The fact that that satisfies the definition of a topology makes it a  topology, even if you haven't explicitly mentioned that it satisfies that definition. $\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$One could express it thus: To specify a particular topology is to say which sets are open. $\qquad$

Comment: @Benjamin You can certainly talk about open sets without naming the specific topology. For example "The union of open sets is open" is true, and you don't need to specify the topology. It's the topology that determines which sets are to be considered open. So SOME statements you can make about open sets are independent of the topology; and some aren't. For example "[0,1] is open in the reals" depends on the topology.